# Loop Through Looped Button Element to Manipulate Looped Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm using JavaScript/jQuery. I'm having an issue with looping through an array to display the data as well as removing contents via button clicks.

**Original Code in Question**

*HTML*

```
<textarea id="sds">Apple
Banana
Grape
Orange</textarea>
<input type="hidden" id="sdh" />
Problem: Every button returns 5!
<div id="popup" title="Poof">
</div>
```

*Script*

```
var sds = $("#sds").val();
var sda = sds.split("\n");
var sdi = "";
$.each(sda, function(k, s) {
    sdi += "<input type='text' id='sd" + k + "' value='" + s + "' /><button id='button" + k + "'>Click Me</button><br />";
    $("#sdh").val(k);
});
$("#popup").html(sdi);

var h = $("#sdh").val();
var i = 0;
while (i <= h) {
    $("#button" + i).click(function() {
        // Here is where I have a problem trying to manipulate the input associated to the button.
        alert(i); // Test to see what returns for the value of i.
        $("#sd" + i).val("Clicked button " + i);
    });
    i++;
}
```

*CSS* (Thanks for providing the CSS to make the demo look better, Jose!)

```
#sds {
    display: none;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KsqUL/1/)

**Revised Code**

*HTML*

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="40" id="sds">Apple
Banana
Grape
Orange</textarea>
<input type="text" id="sd" value="Click here to verify" />
<input type="hidden" id="key" />
<div id="popup" title="Verify Multiple Fruits">
</div>
```

*Script*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sds = $("#sds").val();
    var sda = sds.split("\n");
    var sdi = "";
    $.each(sda, function(key, sd) {
        sdi += "<input type='text' id='sd" + key + "' value='" + sd + "' /><button id='button'" + key + "'>Remove</button><br />";
        alert(key); // Test to see what returns for the value of i.
        $("#button" + key).click(function() {
            // Here is where I have a problem trying to manipulate the input associated to the button.
            $("#sd" + key).val("Clicked button " + i);
        });
        $("#key").val(key);
    });
    $("#popup").html(sdi);
});
$(function() {
    $("#popup").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            "Update": function() {
                var key = $("#key").val();
                var i = 0;
                var sds = "";
                while (i <= key) {
                    sds += $("#sd" + i).val() + "\n";
                    i++;
                }
                sds = sds.slice(0, -1);
                $("#sds").val(sds);
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function() {
        },
        height: 320,
        hide: {
            duration: 1000,
            effect: "explode"
        },
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        show: {
            duration: 1000,
            effect: "blind"
        },
        width: 480
    });
    $("#sd").focus(function() {
        $("#popup").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

*CSS* (Thanks again for the CSS here, Jose!)

```
#sds {
    display: none;
}

#popup input,
#popup button {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}

#popup input {
    clear: left;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KsqUL/4/)

**Revised Code after Applying One of the Answers**

*HTML*

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="40" id="sds">Apple
Banana
Grape
Orange
Pear
Strawberry</textarea>
<input type="text" id="sd" value="Click here to verify." />
<input type="hidden" id="key" />
<div id="popup" title="Verify Multiple Fruits"></div>
```

*Script*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each($("#sds").val().split("\n"), function(key, sd) {
        $("#popup").append(        
            $("<input type='text' id='sd" + key + "' value='" + sd + "' />").add(
                $("<button id='button" + key + "'>Remove</button><br />").click(function() {
                    $("#sd" + key).val("");
                    $("key").val(key);
                })));
    });
});
$(function() {
    $("#popup").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            "Update": function() {
                var key = $("#key").val();
                var i = 0;
                var sds = "";
                while (i <= key) {
                    sds += $("#sd" + i).val() + "\n";
                    i++;
                }
                sds = sds.slice(0, -1);
                $("#sds").val(sds);
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function() {
        },
        height: 320,
        hide: {
            duration: 1000,
            effect: "explode"
        },
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        show: {
            duration: 1000,
            effect: "blind"
        },
        width: 480
    });
    $("#sd").focus(function() {
        $("#popup").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

*CSS* (This is really awesome, Jose!)

```
#sds {
    display: none;
}

#popup input,
#popup button {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}

#popup input {
    clear: left;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KsqUL/5/)

Suppose the value of sds is Apple, Banana, Grape and Orange on different lines. Each button created by the .each() loop will have the correct number assigned, but when trying to change the value, the variable i returns 5 on the alert message box while the next line doesn't seem to work at all - due to the index being off.

How can I revise this code to make it work like it's supposed to?

Corrected the error mentioned by the loving and caring commentators. Still not working. Obviously that wasn't the issue as my original code that I copied off of had the parenthesis closed correctly. I was hand-jamming the code here since I have no ability to copy and paste the code here, so a small typo was made. My question is about the logic, not typo. Thanks!

In order to minimize the confusion, I've revised the code section of this question to reflect the original code I had, so it'll show the consistency with the answers Jose provided below.

Obviously, the revised code also had more issues, so I made a new revision yet again. Here is what I've gotten so far. It's still quirky, but works on most part. I'm going to need help with the cancel action on the modal dialog since it won't bring back the previous values from the textarea tag. Also, please, note the version changes on jQuery and addition of jQuery UI to the JSFiddle demo to reflect my development environment.

**The Ultimate Solution**

*HTML*

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="40" id="sds">Apple
Banana
Grape
Orange
Pear
Strawberry</textarea>
<input type="text" id="sd" value="Click here to verify." />
<div id="popup" title="Verify Multiple Fruits"></div>
```

*Script*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#sds").val()) {
        var i = 0;
        $.each($("#sds").val().split("\n"), function(key, sd) {
            $("#popup").append(        
                $("<input type='text' class='blah' id='sd" + key + "' value='" + sd + "' />").add(
                    $("<button id='button" + key + "'>Remove</button><br />").click(function() {
                        $("#sd" + key).val("");
                    })));
            i++;
            window["i"] = i;
        });
    }
});
$(function() {
    $("#popup").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            "Update": function() {
                var i = window["i"];
                var sds = "";
                $(".blah").each(function(i) {
                    if ($(this).val()) {
                        sds += $("#sd" + i).val() + "\n";
                    }
                });
                sds = sds.slice(0, -1);
                $("#sds").val(sds);
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            $("#popup").html("");
            if ($("#sds").val()) {
                var i = 0;
                $.each($("#sds").val().split("\n"), function(key, sd) {
                    $("#popup").append(        
                        $("<input type='text' class='blah' id='sd" + key + "' value='" + sd + "' />").add(
                            $("<button id='button" + key + "'>Remove</button><br />").click(function() {
                                $("#sd" + key).val("");
                            })));
                    i++;
                    window["i"] = i;
                });
            }
        },
        height: 320,
        hide: {
            duration: 1000,
            effect: "explode"
        },
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        show: {
            duration: 1000,
            effect: "blind"
        },
        width: 480
    });
    $("#sd").focus(function() {
        if ($("#sds").val()) {
            $("#popup").dialog("open");
        }
    });
});
```

*CSS*

```
#sds {
    display: none;
}

#popup input,
#popup button {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}

#popup input {
    clear: left;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KsqUL/16/)

**Thoughts after Solving the Issue**

I was initially irritated by the people who pointed out the typos rather than trying to see the entire picture to discover the "big" flaw with the program itself because that's what I thought I would have done for people who would ask me for guidance. Then, it hit me when I thought about how I would really react when I see petty mistakes like typos and bad grammars. I admit I hate seeing those petty mistakes, mostly because I have an obsessive-compulsive disorder when it comes to writing anything, including codes. Now that I've learned about JSFiddle, I'll test my code there before trying to post a question here from now on. It has been a terrific learning experience and thanks to all for the assistance.

Comment: How do you expect us to help, if your code is full of errors (not to mention the missing markup)? The one pointed out by Hussein Nazzal is just one of them.
Please correct and post it on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Thanks. You should post your code in jsfiddle, because makes easier for us to help you and that way you would still find other syntax errors (`}` missing on `while`). But nevermind, I will provide an answer soon.

Comment: I'll have to explore jsfiddle.net more later. I like the environment. Anyways, I've tried to rewrite the code on my personal web server and tested it to see if I made any other minor errors. I think I've corrected all of those for now. The main problem is the logic on the part that I've inserted comments in the code.

Comment: I think I already solved your problem. In my answer you can live test 3 different jsfiddle solutions.

Comment: I've edited my answer, after you changed the code on the question. At the bottom of it, you can see what you need to change. I didn't tested but should work.

Comment: Sorry about the change. I didn't mean to make it more complicated. You still nailed it! Thanks again!

Comment: `$("key").val(key);` is wrong. Should be `$("#key").val(key);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this problem.

### **Use a closure**

Inside the loop, declare an anonymous function and call it immediately, passing in `i` as the  parameter `local_i`. In other words, `i` has a global scope, but the `local_i` has a scope limited to the anonymous function. This way, the click event "sees" the `local_i` value, not the `i` (5) as you had before.

```
while (i <= h) {
    (function (local_i) {
        $("#button" + local_i).click(function() {
            alert(local_i); // Test to see what returns for the value of i.
            $("#sd" + local_i).val("Clicked button " + local_i);
        });
    })(i); // <-- HERE I am calling the function
    i++;
}
```

[**Click here for a live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mU9Uv/3/)

---

### **Get the index from the button id**

There is one pattern here: You want `i=0` for `#button0`, `i=1` for `#button1`.
So, just get the index from the id. This solution requires no loops.

```
// select all buttons inside #popup, that have an id starting by "button"
$("#popup button[id^=button]").click(function() {
    var i = parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace('button', ''));
    alert(i); // Test to see what returns for the value of i.
    $("#sd" + i).val("Clicked button " + i);
});
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mU9Uv/4/)

---

### **Optimized version, no loops, no global variables**

```
$.each($("#sds").val().split("\n"), function(k, s) {
    $("#popup").append(

        // append the text box
        $("<input type='text' id='sd" + k + "' value='" + s + "' />").add(

            // and the button with the click already defined
            $("<button id='button" + k + "'>Click Me</button>").click(function() {
                alert(k);
                $("#sd" + k).val("Clicked button " + k);
            }))
    );
});
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mU9Uv/6/)

---

### **Final Solution**

Brand new code was pasted into the question. To fix the problem in that code, just change

```
$("#button" + key).click(function() {
   // Here is where I have a problem trying to manipulate the input associated to the button.
   $("#sd" + key).val("Clicked button " + i);
});
```

to

```
$("#button" + key).click(function() {
   var i = $(this).attr('id').replace('button', '');
   $("#sd" + i).val("Clicked button " + i);
});
```

You can use the other alternatives I wrote above.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow! You're really good! It wasn't really a new code. I was rewriting it to make it more presentable instead of having all kinds of minor distracting errors in it. You definitely know your stuff. I know there are always more than one way to solve a problem, and you showed me quite a few possible ways to tackle my issue. Thanks again!

Comment: Ugh! It works fine until I tried to turn the div into a modal dialog as I've changed the code on the question. Somehow, it works by itself, but won't show up at all on the modal dialog. I haven't tried all possible solutions, but the optimized answer doesn't want to append the HTML properly. I'll try the other ways and see what happens.

Comment: I see a bug in your code: In line `sdi += "<input type='text'....<button id='button'"`, the `id='button'"` is wrong. Remove the single quote after `button`. It should be `sdi += "<input type='text' id='sd" + key + "' value='" + sd + "' /><button id='button" + key + "'>Remove</button><br />"`

Comment: I see that error, too. It's been fixed on the final revision though. Still working on bringing back the values after clicking cancel.

Comment: Came up with http://jsfiddle.net/KsqUL/6/ so far. I see a problem with the Update action as well. I'm still working on it.

Comment: Grrr! I notice the typo I made with $("key") on line 7.

Comment: I'm getting so close. It's working like it's supposed to on the first Update, but when I remove a fruit again and Update for the second time, everything disappears. http://jsfiddle.net/KsqUL/8/

Comment: Okay! I think I finally got it.

Answer (score 1):

you have an error here

`$("#button" + i.click(function() {`

it should be

`$("#button" + i).click(function() {`

corrent that and it will work.